# insert xml into SQL oracle database

Tags: sql, xml

I have xml file :

```xml
<bookstore> 
    <book category="cooking"><title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title> <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author> <year>2005</year><price>30.00</price></book>
    <book category="children"><title lang="en">Harry Potter</title><author>J K. Rowling</author><year>2005</year><price>29.99</price></book>
</bookstore>
```

I need to insert books information into oracle database table "Books" with columns defined according to the xml data attributes as category, title, etc.

Any idea how yo do so ? thank you.

Comment: this is the xml file which I need to import into DB <bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
</bookstore>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert xml into XmlType field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664377/insert-xml-into-xmltype-field)